# Find matches ending with a letter that is not a starting letter of the next match

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

**Intro**

I have a string containing diagnosis codes (ICD-10), not separated by any character. I would like to extract all valid diagnosis codes. Valid diagnosis codes are of the form

[Letter][between 2 and 4 numbers][optional letter that is not the next match starting letter]

The regex for this pattern is (I believe)

```
\w\d{2,4}\w?
```

**Example**

Here is an example

```
mystring='F328AG560F33'
```

In this example there are three codes:

`'F328A'` `'G560'` `'F33'`

I would like to extract these codes with a function like str_extract_all in R (preferably but not exclusively)

**My solution so far**

So far, I managed to come up with an expression like:

```
str_extract_all(mystring,pattern='\\w\\d{2,4}\\w?(?!(\\w\\d{2,4}\\w?))')
```

However when applied to the example above it returns

```
"F328"  "G560F"
```

Basically it misses the letter A in the first code, and misses altogether the last code "F33" by mistakenly assigning F to the preceding code.

**Question**

What am I doing wrong? I only want to extract values that end with a letter that is not the start of the next match, and if it is, the match should not include the letter.

**Application**

This question is of great relevance for example when mining patient Electronic Health Records that have not been validated.

Comment: Please update your answer and use the built in formatting tools to format your code examples.

Comment: Can you explain why you've written your regex the way you do?

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I wrote the regex that way because I thought I needed to "tell the regex engine to match the longest possible pattern that is not followed by a valid pattern".

As both Xophmeister  and Wiktor pointed out, this was not the right approach.

Comment: Ah, yes! I had tried earlier but couldn't bc of low rep. You are a keen observer :)
If not too much bother would you mind explaining one thing: in your suggested regex you wrap the optional letter in a non-capturing group. So the optional letter should really not be captured. And still it does! What gives?

Comment: @Gino_JrDataScientist A non-capturing group only prevents from creating a memory buffer for the part of the match captured with the group pattern(s). However, these patterns are still *consuming*, i.e. the chars they match are added to the match/capture. In the pattern below, there is an outer capturing group inside the lookahead. That means that `(a(?:bc)?)` will still capture `abc` if there is `abc` in the input string, but there will be no second capture group for `bc` in the match data object.

Comment: I see. Basically I didn't know the difference between capturing and consuming. Guess I have to finally start learning the basics :)
Thank you for the clear and pedagogic explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matches are overlapping. In this case, you might use `str_match_all` that allows easy access to capturing groups and use a pattern with a positive lookahead containing a capturing group inside:

```
(?i)(?=([A-Z]\d{2,4}(?:[A-Z](?!\d{2,4}))?))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cId2gV/1)

**Details**

- `(?=` - a positive lookahead start (it will be run at every location before each char and at the end of the string
- `(` - Group 1 start

  - `[A-Z]` - a letter (if you use a case insensitive modifier `(?i)`, it will be case insensitive)
  - `\d{2,4}` - 2 to 4 digit
  - `(?:` - an optional non-capturing group start:

    - `[A-Z]` - a letter
    - `(?!\d{2,4})` - not followed with 2 to 4 digits
  - `)?` - the optional non-capturing group end
- `)` - Group 1  end
- `)` - Lookahead end.

R demo:

```
> library(stringr)
> res <- str_match_all("F328AG560F33", "(?i)(?=([A-Z]\\d{2,4}(?:[A-Z](?!\\d{2,4}))?))")
> res[[1]][,2]
[1] "F328A" "G560"  "F33"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This regex works for the task that I described.
I chose this answer because it seems also resilient to ill-specified diagnosis codes and "noise" like punctuation.
For example with the string
'F33%10CB1203SA12  F2¤1' it will return  "F33" "B1203S" "A12" which is precisely what I want.

Comment: I just don't quite understand why it works. I know you broke your regex down, and thanks for that! I guess I just need to understand this lookahead business better. Thanks again!

Comment: this answer is actually not completely right: in the example I gave the expected result was "F328A" "G560" "F33"  while your demo gives the following "F328A" "G560F" "F33"
The problem is  that the second code has an extra F in the end..

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Gino_JrDataScientist Where is the `F` gone then? It is optional in the pattern and it is there inside the string.

Comment: @Gino_JrDataScientist Ok, I will fix it in a minute or two if it is fixable.

Comment: yes the F is in the pattern but it belongs to the following code because "F33" is a valid code. If the string had been

"F328AG560F3"

then the expected result should be  "F328A" "G560F" because F3 is not a valid code

Comment: I see, please next time explain the match boundaries more precisely, it makes a huge difference for regexps since you need to also account for *context*, not just the type of chars that may or may not appear.

Comment: Will do. Sorry I am very new to this.. How would you have explained the match boundaries, may I ask?

Comment: @Gino_JrDataScientist, OK, found, I think it is [`(?=([A-Z]\\d{2,4}(?:[A-Z](?!\\d{2,4}))?))`](https://regex101.com/r/cId2gV/1)

Comment: @Gino_JrDataScientist: You spoke about longest/shortest matches, but that is irrelevant. What you need to specify is that you only want to extract values that must end with a letter that is not the start of the next match.

Comment: @Gino_JrDataScientist See my final update. It should work well for all inputs now.

Answer (score 2):

You have a letter, two-to-four numbers then an optional letter. That optional letter, if it's there, will only ever be followed by another letter; or, put another way, never followed by a number. You can write a negative lookahead to capture this:

```
\w\d{2,4}(?:\w(?!\d))?
```

This at least [works with PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/Okj1w3/1). I don't know about how R will handle it.

Comment: For some reason this regex returns also codes starting with a number..
For example with '328AG560F33' it returns
'328A' 'G560' 'F33'
I know I did not specify that there can be invalid patterns.. So this answer is valid for the question I posed.
However, Wiktor's regex seem to handle well also broken patterns like this one.

Thank you for your very good answer in any case! :)

Comment: @Gino_JrDataScientist No, do not use `[A-z]`. [It matches more than letters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926)

Comment: **EDIT** it's my fault: in my question I said that the regex for a valid pattern is with \w whereas it should have been [A-z]

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew!!  I really did not know about it